# Checking the continuity of the given function

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the set of reals and, $\tau$ be the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by the union of $\tau_{1}$, the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and $\tau_{2}$, the topology of countable complements on $\mathbb{R}$ (This is the example 63 of "Counterexamples in Topology, L. A. Steen and J. A. Seebach). Is the map $(\Bbb R,\tau)\times (\Bbb R,\tau)\to (\Bbb R,\tau)$ define by $(x,y)\longmapsto x+y$ continuous? Unfortunately, my efforts did not work.